# Dúvidas sobre o uso do Git

Tags: git, versionamento

Criei um novo projeto no Github e depois tentei dar o `git push` para subir os arquivos que estavam na minha máquina. Fiz os procedimentos básicos necessários (acho) para dar certo, mas está dando erro de `failed to push some refs`.

Segui mais ou menos [este tutorial](http://codexico.com.br/blog/linux/tutorial-simples-como-usar-o-git-e-o-github/) (a partir do 2º passo, o restante já havia feito).

Outra coisa que não entendo são os conceitos de `master`, `branches` e `merge`. Já olhei [este guia](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html), mas ainda estou perdido.

[image: Erro na hora do push]

Comment: Outro detalhe é que estou usando https pois estou no serviço e aqui é bloqueado ssh.

Comment: Nossa, agora entendi essas correções no meu post Rodrigo, dessa vez agradeço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa primeiro puxar as alterações que as outras pessoas fizeram (com `git pull`), integrá-las ao seu projeto para então subir as suas alterações (com `git push`).

Outra coisa: esse procedimento vale para o Git, e não necessariamente para a hospedagem do Github. Pode ser também Bitbucket ou mesmo uma solução *in-house*.

Sobre sua dúvidas quanto ao uso do Git, recomendo esses dois links:

- http://try.github.io/ – um tutorial interativo sobre os comandos mais comuns do Git, e
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows – um documento descrevendo diversas maneiras de se trabalhar com Git, todas elas muito bem explicativas!

Comment: Rodrigo, mas ninguém fez nada. É coisa minha mesmo.

A qual é mano? Deu certo depois que dei o git pull meu_diretorio... ;\ ai dei outro git push e foi. Porque isso?

Comment: @phpricardo você adicionou os arquivos (`git add ...`), declarou o repositório remoto (`git remote add origin ...`), fez o commit (`git commit -m 'mensagem'`) e, enfim, tentou dar o push (`git push`)?

Comment: Foi isso mesmo.

Comment: Tente dar um `git pull estudos master` e depois dar um `git push estudos master`. É exatamente isso o que diz a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo que você leia [Git Guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/). Algumas considerações:

- Você pode criar uma repositório local, e depois adicionar uma origem
- você pode clonar um projeto

No final os 2 acima darão o mesmo resultado.

Depos de ter um projeto, você precisa versionar o seu código (suas alterações):

1. Você tem de adicionar os arquivos na index do `git`, algo assim:

   ```
   c:\>projeto\git add *
   ```
2. Dar o `commit`:

   ```
   c:\>projeto\git commit -m "Coisas que fiz no código"
   ```
3. Neste momento o seu código já esta versionado! Mas esse versionamento é local para enviá-lo para o servidor você tem de fazer um `push` :

   ```
   c:\>projeto\git push origin master
   ```

Comment: Foi isso que eu estava fazendo mesmo Bruno, porém no git push estava dando o erro. Mas logo após parecer do Rodrigo executei o comando git pull projeto e logo após git push novamente dando certo. 
ps.: Descobri agora pouco que esse origin (é um apelido) agora essa "parada" de master, branches que não estou entendendo.

Comment: Quando vc cria um repositório em GIT, tudo fica dentro de branch's, mas por default se vc não criar e especificar nada, o branch a ser usando será o `master` nesse link tem uma explicação de como organizar os branch's  http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/